# Как включить cURL в php.ini?

Tags: denwer, curl, php

Вот ошибка:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in Z:\denwer\www\denwer\index.php on line 4`

Answer (score 1):

Заходишь в php.ini нажимаешь ctrl+f пишешь curl, жмешь enter находится строка. Раскоментируй(удали точку с запятой вначале) ее, перезагрузи сервер и будет тебе счастье.)

Comment: после этих действий с php.ini "(удали точку с запятой вначале)"страница не звгружается, что делать?

Comment: гуглить и исправлять ошибки которые выводит